# How to change the python version used on google colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to install this repo :

https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/MonocularTotalCapture

on google colab. This is how I have installed conda and opencv=2.4.13 (it requires python 2.7 to work)

```
pip install conda

!wget -c https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh

!bash ./Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local

import sys

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/')

!conda install -y -q -c conda-forge opencv=2.4.13
```

Between the others packages,it requires also pyEDM,so I'm trying to install it. I'm following this guide :

https://github.com/SugiharaLab/pyEDM/issues/1

I don't get any error until this command :

```
!cd pyEDM; pip install .
```

that gives to me this error :

```
Processing /content/pyEDM
ERROR: Package 'pyEDM' requires a different Python: 2.7.15 not in '>=3'
```

Infact when I ask which versions of python I have,it says :

```
!python2 --version
Python 2.7.15

!python3 --version
Python 3.6.9

!echo $PYTHONPATH
/tensorflow-1.15.0/python3.6:/env/python
```

So,I should change the python version installed by conda when I have installed opencv 2.4.13 to a version of 3 or greater,otherwise the package can't be installed. On my local machine I would do that with this command :

```
!alias python='/usr/bin/python3.6'
```

but it does not work on colab. When I give the alias command it doesn't answer anything and the error is still there. What can I do ?

Comment: When you install Anaconda, you are installing an entirely separate Python stack from the one within Colab, and you'll have to make certain the installed packages are compatible. In general, there is no good way to do that, so the approach you are using is not recommended.

Comment: which approach do u reccomend ?

Comment: I saw that you've been having issues with this same library, have you seen [Using Pip in a Conda Environment](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/) ?

Comment: I would recommend installing packages without conda. Colab runs on linux, so a combination of apt and pip usually is sufficient. But if opencv requires Python 2.7 and pyEDM requires Python 3.6, you'll never be able to use them together in the same Python environment, regardless of how you install them.